# Is there a safe way to modify another package's entry in the RPM database?

Tags: installation, rpm, rpm-spec

I've run into the problem described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/997045/preun-is-passed-with-value-0-to-1-during-upgrade), where an old package was Obsoleted, and its %preun script is run with $1 = 0, resulting in undesirable behavior.  I know this could be worked around by using -e + -i, as suggested in that answer, or the --nopreun flag, but it's difficult to get that information out to users who are accustomed to simply using -U.

I can't modify the existing %preun scripts in the wild.  I don't see any way to run additional code from the new package after the old one's preun.  I can't find any way to have my new package programmatically prevent the old %preun script from executing.

Is there any safe way to reach into the RPM database and remove a scriptlet for an existing package?

Answer (score 1):

Jeff Johnson is absolutely correct that it **should** not be done. However it certainly can be done.

I have done this in an RPM at work, for distribution, but note, this was a contained semi-structured environment with **no** remote hands to all systems.
If you have remote hands access, take the "remove, install" path, and script that.

If you really feel you should be doing this, then these are the pointers. I'm not going to show you exactly how I did it because it was "work" and not mine to share. The concepts are mine :-)

First, back up the /var/lib/rpm/Packages file (`cp /var/lib/rpm/Packages /var/tmp/Packages.bkp`). Put it somehwere safe. Update your backup if any one else changes the system whilst you are working on your solution. MAke regular checks on the count of RPMs and test every which way from Sunday, after each change or step.

You will need to use the db_unload and db_load commands. For speed, you will need to use "s2p" to convert any shell sed patterns to perl. Then build a pipe which looks like this:

`db_unload /var/tmp/Packages.bkp |perl -i -e "s2p converted string" |db_load /var/tmp/Packages.new`

You can then attempt to test the Packages.new by copying ot over the original. Always run rpm --rebuilddb after manual changes. If you see **any** errors, restore the back up and rebuild the db again.

If you need to put it in an RPM, then convert it to Lua, and put it in the pretrans or posttrans scriptlet (`%pretrans -p <lua>`). The selection depends on the ordering you are trying to achieve. The Lua interpreter is built in to rpm, and so it will run OK during a new system install even if your RPM gets called somehow. I wrapped my "pipe" in a lua long string, and made it only execute if the system already exists. It does nothing otherwise. If you are thinking "that will never happen" then check out "Never say Never".

BTW you can completely stiff your RPM base and thus future administration of the system if you mess this up. If you do that, and have no backup or way out, it would be a hard way to learn that you are responsible for your own actions. Just saying that you have been warned!

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot edit an rpmdb: the headers are protected
from change by a SHA1 or a digital signature.

Instead upgrade to a fixed version of the package using --nopreun
to prevent running the buggy script let.